# Need text in one line with overflow hidden inside a LI element

Tags: html, css

i have this html code:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 325px">
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td style="width: 100%">
              <ul>
                  <li>TEXT 1</li>
                  <li>I DONT WANT YOU TO SEE ME IN MORE THAN 1 LINE</li>
                  <li>TEXT3</li>                   
                  <li>NEED THIS IN ONE LINE WITH OVERFLOW HIDDEN</li>
              </ul>
          </td>
          <td style="vertical-align: top">
              <input type="button" value="...">
          </td>
          <td style="vertical-align: top">
              <input type="button" value="*">
          </td>
          <td style="vertical-align: top">
              <input type="button" value="X">
          </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need that the LI elements that its text exceeds the width of the TD instead of breaking a new line, hide the overflow text.

[I have this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7gjcL0uq/5/)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: CSS `white-space:nowrap;`

Comment: @pablito.aven answer should be ans box not in comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7gjcL0uq/7/)**

```
ul li 
{
    border:1px solid blue ;
   text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:90%; /* change this value according to your need */

}
```